# How Simulation RSSI in Contiki OS?

Tags: contiki

How i can find **RSSI** simulation for **contiki-os**?
in the contiki-os (instance), You can find RSSI-Scanner and Not Find RSSI!
I need to Run RSSI and When Run RSSI-Scanner, This Not Work Correctly!
is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Contiki also supports to convert ETX to RSSI and vice versa if you use RPL. You can find source code /net/ipv6/link-stats.c